# Special Charcter Issue in XML Creation using SQLXMLBULKLOADLib - C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, special-characters, sqlxml

I am trying to load csv file using SQLXMLBULKLOADLib which first converts csv to xml and then maps it to database model. My cvs file contains special character. When SQLXMLBULKLOADLib loads it in XML, the special characters are converted to different representation like `&#x1A;, &#x15;, &#x14;` etc. I am not aware of what `&#x1A;, &#x15;, &#x14;` is. **How to handle this in XML and SQL Server?** I need to show the exact special character available in csv file.

Comment: are these characters representing a different language? or is it control characters?

Comment: Not sure but our client's legacy system has this characters and they want it the same way in new system we are developing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got answer from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-au/sqlxml/thread/5c46314d-ec4c-4ec2-91c9-7ceb466af3c6